# Setting up SSL on nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm trying to set up SSL with Nginx, however I'm having a few problems. I received all the required files, and created the bundle as shown [here](https://aralbalkan.com/scribbles/setting-up-ssl-with-nginx-using-a-namecheap-essentialssl-wildcard-certificate-on-digitalocean/), and added it to my site configuration as below:

```
server {
    listen 443;

    server_name <domain> www.<domain>;

    ssl_certificate /srv/ssl/<domain>.bundle.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /srv/ssl/<domain>.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name <domain> www.<domain>;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
    }
}
```

When trying to connect I get an SSL connection error. However, running `diff <(openssl rsa -in /srv/ssl/<domain>.key -modulus -noout) <(openssl x509 -in /srv/ssl/<domain>.bundle.cer -modulus -noout)` returns nothing.

Nginx error log shows the following:

```
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/srv/ssl/<domain>.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
```

The bundle was created using `cat`:

```
 cat <domain>.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > <domain>.bundle.cer
```

The Nginx user has permissions to read the files.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? How did you create your certificate chain? It's not sufficient to link to some guide; you need to describe what you actually did.

Comment: Added more info. As I mentioned, the problem is that you cannot establish a secure connection (Chrome shows `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`)

Comment: That error suggests that your private key doesn't match the certificate you are using. Did you upload the wrong file?

Comment: Nope, files are correct. Also, if I use create a Node.js file, and use `https.createServer`, it works fine. Also, as you can see from diff, the files match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mark the port 443 as ssl-enabled in nginx. `listen 443 ssl;` - kind of.